# Develop a chrome extension to capture clicks using chrome extension api

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a chrome extension which can capture clicks using chrome extension APIs not by JavaScript.

Comment: There's [no such API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index).

Comment: I am referring to this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index

Comment: That's the same link I gave.

Comment: I think it can be done using this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/input_ime but I don't know how.

Comment: That's only on Chrome OS as stated in the header. You can see examples linked in the documentation.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish (i.e. the purpose of your extension) and then maybe others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the 'click' events in chrome extension, this answer might help you from the question - [How may I get the element attributes (text, id, class and so on..) of the current tab, out of a mouse click, from a chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921227/how-may-i-get-the-element-attributes-text-id-class-and-so-on-of-the-curren)

In your content.js, write the following code-

```
$(window).click(function(event) {
    console.log("Click event: ", event);
});
```

[Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) are files that run in the context of web pages. By using the standard Document Object Model (DOM), they are able to read details of the web pages the browser visits, make changes to them and pass information to their parent extension.